# Passing value between two components (pages) in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am using Angular 2 (TypeScript)

I have two components (actually they are two pages too). They are NOT parent and child relationship.

I want to pass a value to second component(page) when I click the link in the first component(page).

I know "URL parameters" way through router. But I don't want to show this parameter in the link. Is there any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use a service, which is a common way to share data between components.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The canonical way is to establish an `injectable` service and inject the service into any components that need the data.  Since the service is a singleton, the components will be accessing the same data. It shouldn't matter that they are on different pages. [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HX5dsl7I8IkGJhOL1wBr?p=preview).

> **Edit:** Here's a more involved example that shows two-way communication between components by subscribing to an eventEmitter on a service: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JU0s7nNZVM9Cmq8ZVov9?p=preview)

```
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

// your shared service 
// provide reference in parent component or bootstrap 
@Injectable()
export class myService {
  sharedData:string = "String from myService"
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page1',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <b>Component Page1 - shared data:</b> {{SharedData}}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [],
})
export class Page1 {
  constructor(aService: myService) {
    this.SharedData = aService.sharedData
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page2',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <b>Component Page2 - shared data:</b> {{SharedData}}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [],
})
export class Page2 {
  constructor(aService: myService) {
    this.SharedData = aService.sharedData
  }
}
```

Comment: @HongboMiao, the code above will not work.  Since Page1 and Page2 both "provide" service myService, they each get their own instance of the service.  (MarkM, services are not necessarily singletons in Angular 2 -- it depends on where you provide them.)  The Plunker is correct though, since myService is provided at the bootstrap/root component level, hence Page1 and Page2 get the same instance.

Comment: @MarkRajcok thanks for letting me know. I got idea from your and his answer. I think I met the problem you mentioned, different instances. Since I only need share a string, so I finally use a static string in a service.

Comment: @HongboMiao, I would not recommend a static string to solve your problem.  All you need to do is put a single `providers: [myService]` line in some component that is above the two components that need to share the data. That way, they'll both get the same/single instance.  If your app only needs one instance of this service, put it in the root component, or use the bootstrap method as the plunker shows.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I think I got some after reading some blogs and your answer, I will change to using providers these days when I get time. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for catching that oversight @MarkRajcok - I edited the answer. I think the second plunker is a more complete solution if you want actually pass data back and forth.

Comment: I would have edited it, but I wanted to find out why Hongbo thought it worked.  Anyway, I wish you many upvotes with the corrected version :).

Answer (score 9):

Thank you MarkM! 
It works, but it has been difficult for me because I have it all in diferent files and over last angular2 using angular cli... So I explain it here:

First of all: 
You need to create a file with the class you want to share with other components: **data.service.ts** and make it "@Injectable":

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class myService {
  public sharedData:string;

  constructor(){
    this.sharedData = "String from myService";
  }

  setData (data) {
    this.sharedData = data;
  }
  getData () {
    return this.sharedData;
  }
}
```

Make sure you set the created class (myService) on 'providers' only once on the **app.module.ts** file and import the injectable file: **data.service.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppContent } from './components/content.component';
import { AppInsertContent } from './components/insert.component';
import { myService } from './services/data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppContent,
    AppInsertContent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [appRoutingProviders, myService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Wherever you want to use your shared class use the constructor to create an object from the class (this object will be unique for your components, thanks to the @Injectable decorator). Remember to import it on every file you use it!...

In my case this view sets the data of the object with a text input: **input.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { myService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'insert-content',
  template: `
   <input id="textbox" #textbox type="text">
   <button (click)="this._myService.setData(textbox.value); SharedData = textbox.value;">SAVE</button>
   Object data: {{SharedData}}

    <div class="full-button">
      <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">BACK</a>
    </div>
  `
})

export class AppInsertContent {
  SharedData: string;
  constructor (private _myService: myService){
    console.log(this._myService.getData());
  }
}
```

And in this view I just see the data that has been set on the object: **content.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { myService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  template: `
  <div style="float:left; clear:both;"> 
    {{_myService.getData()}} 
  </div>

  <div class="full-button">
    <a routerLink="/insert" routerLinkActive="active">INSERT</a>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppContent {
  constructor (private _myService: myService){
    console.log(this._myService.getData());
  }
}
```

I hope this info is usefull!

Comment: Dude, you saved my life! Just by saying: "Make sure you set the created class (myService) on 'providers' only once on the app.module.ts".

Thank you so much, I couldn't save my data into the service because I put it on every component instead of only in app.module.ts !

Comment: Thank you very much..!! It was very useful.