# EventEmitter doesn't work for Angular 2 (Beta) even for the same component

Tags: events, typescript, angular

I am having this code where I am making a mouseover and then I want to trigger a custom event for the same component (let alone a bubbling event that I would need `(^mouseover)` notation)

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {EntityModel} from "../../models/clauses/entity";

@Component({
    selector: 'suggestion-entry',
    events: ["selecto"],
    template:
    `<div (mouseover)="emitSuggestionClicked(entry)" (selecto)="selectWorked()">{{entry.text}}

     </div>
    `
})
export class SuggestionEntryComponent {
    @Input() entry: EntityModel;
    @Output() selecto: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    emitSuggestionClicked(clickedEntry:EntityModel): void {
        console.log(clickedEntry);
        this.selecto.emit(clickedEntry);
    }

    selectWorked() {
      alert("select worked");
    }
}
```

I really can't spot what's wrong. I even tried `this.selecto.next(clickedEntry);`  I would appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the parent can listen to the event as far as I know. Events emitted by `EventEmitter` don't bubble. `(^event)` was removed.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the github discussion saying that custom events are bubbling by default..What if we need communication of components that are siblings and not in parent-child relation?

Comment: That was changed to not bubbling only (no way to opt in). To communicate between components and directives that are not parent and child use a shared service (event bus) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959579/passing-value-between-two-components-pages-in-angular-2/34959844#34959844

Comment: I see.. I will go with the services I guess.. what is the point for the same component not to catch its own events? There is no bubbling involved in this case..

Comment: For  `<div (selecto)="selectWorked()"></div>` to work,  the `<div>` needed  to fire the event. In this direction (element class to template) value binding `[property]="elementField"` can be used. I would need more information about your use case to suggest the right way to do it.

Comment: Well div didn't fire the event (mouseover) ? I don't care about property binding it is more procedural what I am trying to make.. I want to have two suggestion menu components and a contenteditable component.. whenever something is clicked in the suggetion menu components (children of the contenteditable component) something should happen on the contenteditable component.. I just started with the very simple case of the events since bubbling up was not working :/

Comment: I would say it does. The browser fires the mouseover with the `<div>` as source. The component could also do this if it's important. `elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('selecto')` I'm not sure if the syntax is 100% correct but I guess you get the idea.

Comment: sure that would but then we go back to the old way of handling events that is really difficult to track :) Thanks though :)